# why doesn't the page load on mobile browsers?

Tags: pageload

Any ideas why this page won't load on media devices? I have tested it with iphone and ipad in chrome, firefox & safari. none of them loads! I even created a directory in my own portfolio and tested it there just to check if the problem was with gh-pages. It still didn't load.

https://ali-shariatii.github.io/meditation-app/

Comment: Not sure how you tried, it is loading in android mobile browser.

Comment: Maybe add which mobile device you are using, which browser, which versions? also see [how to debug on mobile?](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging)